# How to make a Control move left/right only using the mouse pointer?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm currently making a game, it contains a paddle (called `base`) that must move from left to right *only*.

I found a piece of code that allowed the platform to move, however it moves in all directions and isn't synced with my mouse pointer properly:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    base.Location = MousePosition
End Sub
```

What do I need to change or add in order for the paddle to only move horizontally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your *paddle* (I'm naming the Control `paddle` here, `base` is not a good name) is placed near the bottom of the Form, its Height ~25 pixels and its bottom distance from the Form's bottom side ~10-20 pixels.

- You can clip the Cursor to a narrow band right above it when the Mouse enters the Form.
- You can then move the Cursor without intersecting other Controls in the Form, which could interfere with the generation of `MouseMove` events.
- You can also hide the Cursor, so the arrow pointer doesn't become visually obnoxious (unless it's required for something else, of course).
- When the Cursor is moved, the movement is translated to the middle of the paddle Control, which is moved only to the left or right, in relation to the current Cursor offset:
  (`PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X - (paddle.Width \ 2)`)
- When the Form closes, restore the Cursor and the clipping region.

---

Paste this code inside the Form that contains the paddle (and rename `base` to `paddle`):

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseEnter(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseEnter(e)
    ClipCursor()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(e As MouseEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)
    paddle.Left = PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X - (paddle.Width \ 2)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(e As FormClosingEventArgs)
    ShowCursor()
    MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
End Sub

Private Sub ClipCursor()
    Dim bandLocation = New Point(
        Left + 8 + (paddle.Width \ 2), 
        Bottom - paddle.Height * 2 - Cursor.Size.Height)
    Dim bandSize = New Size(ClientSize.Width - paddle.Width, 20)
    Cursor.Clip = New Rectangle(bandLocation, bandSize)
    Cursor.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub ShowCursor()
    Cursor.Clip = Rectangle.Empty
    Cursor.Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by only assigning the X coordinate to the location property:

```
base.Location = New Point(Cursor.Position.X, Button1.Location.Y)
```

This will ignore the Y coordinate, resulting only in horizontal movement. Also, be aware that depending on your situation, you may have to translate the mouse pointer coordinates relative to the window. So, in case the result is distorted, do it like this:

```
base.Location = New Point(PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X, Button1.Location.Y)
```

This will translate the mouse coordinates (from e.g. Cursor.Position property) into window-relative coordinates.

Comment: I tried this, and it does work, however the paddle is stuck at the top of the screen instead of the bottom. How do I make it so that the paddle still moves left/right only but remains at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: You can simply adjust its initial position to be at the bottom of the screen, either using the designer or via code: `base.Location = New Point(base.Location.X, Me.Size.Height-base.Size.Height)`