# VB.NET - How to move the mouse in a specific range in the panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, mouseevent, panel

Visual Basic.Net

Hello everyone.

[image: In this image] , there is a panel.

What I want to do is moving the mouse in specific range in the panel.

When the mouse will be in the panel , I want the mouse to move in specific range.

What I mean by specific range ?

I mean by that , Moving the mouse in X Axis from `95` to `493`.

And moving the mouse in Y Axis start from `30.5`.

and this specific range in the panel.

How can I do this ?

Comment: See the `ClipCursor()` method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905785/7444103) (assuming you have a WinFoms app, otherwise, be specific)